# In Joomla using JHTML::calendar, is there a way to output Day, mm,dd?

Tags: joomla3.0

It's pretty straight forward to use
   echo JHTML::calendar('', 'date', 'dob', '%Y-%m-%d');  to get the date as 2014-07-01.  Is there a way to get Tue 07-01?  I don't need the year.  I can't find any reference to getting the actual day of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit you need to update is `%Y-%m-%d` - This is formatting the date.

I think it is using this system : http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html and so `%D %m-%d` should work, though I haven't had chance to test that.

edit: %a seems to work instead of %D for the day

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that with output: %D 07-01.  I'll check your suggested link.